# AHK debugging: How to check line number of execution, when manually pausing a script?

Tags: debugging, scripting, autohotkey

Is there a way to get the line number of the current line being executed by the AHK script, when I manually pause it?

Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks 
Sunny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you double-click the icon in the system tray, or right-click and choose "Open", the window that opens shows you a list of the most recently executed lines of the script, with line numbers. This should show you exactly what had been executing when you paused.